# Why is my http library's error handler catching *all* runtime errors in the app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a prototype app using React Native 0.39 that requests some data from a remote source. To make the request, I use [Axios.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios)

The call seems pretty straightforward. In a component named `TownsList.js`, I do

```
class TownsList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {towns: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    let url = "(SOME URL HERE)";

    axios.get(url)
         .then(function(response) {
           // Do stuff witt the successful result
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           Alert.alert(
             'Download failed',
             'Unable to download data from '+url+"\nError:"+error,
             [{text: 'OK'}])
         });

...
```

The weird thing now is that whenever I  have some other runtime error in my code within `// Do stuff witt the successful result` block - for example an incorrectly cased reference to some constant or variable - that error will be handled by Axios' error handler, as well:

[image]

That doesn't feel right. What am I doing wrong? Should I set up "generic" error handling somewhere else in my app to catch these things? Or is this intended behaviour?

Comment: ary you using try block anywhere in the code?

Comment: @Codesingh no, a search for the "try" keyword in the entire project turns up no hits

Comment: Can you show the code inside the promise (`then`)

Comment: Dollars to donuts, the actual error is in coded called from `// Do stuff witt the successful result`.  If you don't want that to happen, call the `.catch()` (and re-raise the error) before the `.then()`.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Could you share the code in the `Do stuff witt the successful result`-block? If an error is thrown in the `then`-handler, it will be caught by the `catch`.

Comment: @Tholle it updates the component's state using `this.setState()` - and of course that triggers a re-render of the component and its children. The error is from rendering a sub-component, so I guess it makes sense it gets caught here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, that's interesting. Never seen that occur before. Makes sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the natural behavior if an error is thrown within the block you marked as

```
// Do stuff witt the successful result
```

If you don't want that behavior, consider writing it this way:

```
 axios.get(url)
         .then(function(response) {
           // Do stuff with the successful result
         },
         function (error) {
         // any error from the get() will show up here
           Alert.alert(
             'Download failed',
             'Unable to download data from '+url+"\nError:"+error,
             [{text: 'OK'}])
         });)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
         // any error from "doing stuff" will show up here
         console.error(error);
    })
```

The `.then()` method allows two functions, one for success the other for failure -- failure of the original promise that is, not of the success function.

Since your own code is itself failing for some reason, you certainly don't want to silence that.

Comment: What I'm doing in the `.then()` is update the component's state with the result of the request using `setState()`. The error that is getting caught is a syntax error I made in a subcomponent that indeed gets rendered with the data from the request. It's still not completely intuitive to me why it works this way - I would expect the library to release its error handler when the call finishes successfully -  but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Pekka웃 -- you are overestimating the library's ability to distinguish between different kinds of errors.  Any exception or error thrown in the context of a promise goes to the catch, whether it's a server error, a networking error, or a language error.  The way to distinguish among them is by putting catch functions at different places along the chain.

Answer (score 4):

As Malvolio mentioned, it is the expected behavior when defining a `catch` method on a Promise, everything that throws in it will get catch'ed.

To me though, the best way to handle this kind of behavior would be to use Redux, since it would separate concerns between your component(s) and the data they require. Even if I don't really know your knowledge in the React ecosystem and you said it was only a prototype, I feel it would be best to use this paradigm, the sooner the better. Here are [the motivations](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html) behind Redux, worth a read.

To get started, you'll have to [create a redux store](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html), which can be composed by multiple reducers that will represent small independent partitions of your state, to allow for very controlled access.

You towns reducer could look like this, and would also allow you to get loading and error status:

```js
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions'

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
  err: null
}

export default handleActions({

  FETCHING_TOWNS: state => ({ ...state, isLoading: true })
  FETCH_TOWNS_SUCCESS: (state, { payload }) => ({ data: payload, isLoading: false, err: null })
  FETCH_TOWNS_ERROR: (state, { payload }) => ({ data: [], err: payload, isLoading: false })

}, initialState)
```

And here's an example of what a store creation could be, using `combineReducers`:

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import towns from './towns'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  towns
})

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store
```

To interface your components and the reducers, you'll have to create thunk actions (thus the middleware in the store). *Just be aware this is just one way to handle side effects using redux! There is multiple way to deal with this out there, but this is one of the most easiest and common to begin with*.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions'

const fetchingTowns = createAction('FETCHING_TOWNS')
const fetchTownsError = createAction('FETCH_TOWNS_ERROR')
const fetchTownsSuccess = createAction('FETCH_TOWNS_SUCCESS')

export const fetchTowns = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchingTowns())

  axios.get()
    .then(response => dispatch(fetchTownsSuccess(response)))
    .catch(error => {
       dispatch(fetchTownsError(err))
       Alert.alert(
         'Download failed',
         `Unable to download data from ${url}\nError: ${error}`,
         [{text: 'OK'}]
       )
     });
}
```

To make your components "connected" to your store, meaning they will render again once one of their props changes, you'll have to add the [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) `Provider` component at the top level of your app, and then you could decorate your components, taking only data the component depends on.

Your component would then look like this, and if an error were to occur in the rendering of the child components, it won't get intercepted by the axios Promise, since it has been separated from your Component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@connect(state => ({
  towns: state.towns.data
}), {
  fetchTowns
})
class TownsList extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.fetchTowns()
  }

  render () {
    const { towns } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
       {towns.map(town => (
         <TownComponent town={town} key={town.id}>
       )}
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

I understand this can be a bit obnoxious if you're not familiar with all the new dependencies and the bit of config it adds, but I can assure you it's worth on the long run!

Comment: This is *awesome*! I'm actually getting into Redux right now, still trying to understand it, and wondering how to implement it in my use case. Didn't expect an innocent SO question to deliver a complete custom writeup. :) I'll award Malvolio this bounty and accept the answer because he answers the literal question, but I'll      start a second one for this answer right away. (I will be able to award it in 23 hours.)

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! Decided to get a bit deep into the subject, I agree it might be out-of-scope of your initial question, but since it also resolve the issue, I thought it would be okay, glad you appreciate it ;)

Answer (score -3):

There can be two conditions:-

1) According to me you are using try block anywhere in the code which finds its  catch block in the componentDidMount so that's why other errors are been caught in your catch block.

2) Any warning or error in your code is roaming free and it is been catch by your catch block so i would recommend you to use try block with catch block or try with finally or just finally.

like this:

```
try{
 axios.get(url)
         .then(function(response) {
           // Do stuff witt the successful result
         })
    }
      catch(function (error) {
           Alert.alert(
             'Download failed',
             'Unable to download data from '+url+"\nError:"+error,
             [{text: 'OK'}])
         });
```